# How to get web application directory path in eclipse when I am running my code on Server?

Tags: spring-mvc

```
  URL location = HelloWorldController.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
        System.out.println(location.getFile());
```

It will give an output as

> /C:/Users/MyProjects/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Spring3MVC/WEB-INF/classes/

here Spring3MVC is my dynamic project name

but I want output as C:\Users\Myprojects\workspace\Spring3MVC

How to do this?

Comment: Eclipse build the war and move it to tmp location .. so you are getting this path..i dont think you can get expected path through api..as it is outside the war..

Comment: `System.getProperty("user.dir")` should do the trick

Comment: `System.getProperty("user.dir")` is directory where java was run from, not exactly what you need, which is your project root path in workspace. You can't dynamically get that path from your java code. The way is, set the path in a property file and read it from there. Why exactly you need that path?